# linking laravel and node app with subdomain

Tags: laravel, subdomain, mean, vps

i currently have a running la ravel project,recently i did receive an order to make a web app for client so i made it using MEAN(mongodb,Express,Angular and Node). Unfortunately when i finished the web application the client asked for a demonstration on-line,due to huge difference in location(between me and the client) using my local development environment to showcase the working sample is not an option.i was inquiring if  i could link a url  from the laravel application to the node app without having to buy  a domain

Answer (score 0):

You can create a tunnel to your local environment by using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/)

Follow this steps:

- Download ngrok and unzip ngrok
- Open a cmd / terminal and navigate to ngrok location
- Type the following command:

> ngrok http {your_localhost_server_port_number}

- It will create the tunnel but we need to point a virtual host to it so edit your local virtual host and add an alias / server name like following:
  NOTE: if you only have one app running on your local server this step is optional

> *.ngrok.io

- Now restart your local server to load our new configuration
- Now you are able to see your localhost site online by using the ngrok provided url.
- Enjoy!